# South error when working with multiple databases: django.db.utils.ConnectionDoesNotExist: The connection foo doesn't exist

Tags: django, django-south

I have 2 Django projects with following db settings:

```
DATABASES = {
    'default': {
        'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.postgresql_psycopg2',
        'NAME': 'db1', # 'db2' for second db
        ...
    }
}
```

When trying to sync second db with command

> python manage.py syncdb --database=db2

I receive error

> django.db.utils.ConnectionDoesNotExist: The connection db2 doesn't exist

When I use some other commands, South uses migrations from first project and fills db2 with wrong tables. How to correctly sync/migrate several projects served by single Django + South instance?

Answer (score 5):

The database syncing method does not take the **NAME** key in the **--database** option. As specified earlier, **default** for your **db1** only works.
So you need to setup an additional database dictionary for your **db2**.